# How can I reduce the vertical spacing in a Google document's table of contents?

Tags: google-docs

How can I reduce the vertical spacing in a Google document's table of contents?

For example, in one of my Google document, the vertical spacing in the table of contents used to be fine:

[image]

but after refreshing it, for some reason unknown to me, the vertical spacing has increased:

[image]

I would like to reduce the vertical spacing back to normal, i.e. as shown in the first screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Documents has fixed the issue. Example of a newly generated ToC:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am uncertain what would be causing the change you've noticed. That said, `.navigation-item` has `height` and `line-height` set. Thus, you should be able to modify the spacing to your liking by updating the user style via an add-on such as Stylus or Tampermonkey.

For instance:

```
.navigation-widget-content.goog-container .navigation-item { line-height: .75; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and have only found a manual workaround.  However, as the TOC grows it's getting more difficult.  Mine used to space vertically correctly (i.e. single) and now it defaults to paragraph 4 pts before and 0 pts after. You can highlight all the TOC items and change the 4 pts to 0 pts which fixes the issue.